# How do you tell InstallShield LE which project in the solution to install?

Tags: installshield-le

How do you tell InstallShield LE which project in the solution to install?  I have added the installer project to my solution and I don't see where to tell it which project needs to be included into the install.  Currently it just installs a blank folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authoring installers is development.  InstallShield LE doesn't automagically look at your solution and decide for itself how to deploy your projects.

Take a look at [InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio 2010 Walkthrough](http://codesmartnothard.com/InstallShieldLimitedEditionForVisualStudio2010Walkthrough.aspx) for a high level walkthrough.